# Eloquent hasManyThrough Relationship with multiple Throughs

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to be able to define relationships in Laravel where a "Customer" can be related to "Actions" through "Contacts" or "Equipment" - in the future there may be the requirement to add others too (Quotations for example).

I currently have the relationship setup between "Action", "Equipment" and Customer. So when viewing a "Customer", I can see all of the "Actions" that have been created on "Equipment" that is related to the "Customer".

Obviously, I cannot create a new relationship on the "Customer" model named "Actions" and I cannot find a way to define a single relationship that related through multiple tables.

Storing the "Customer" in the "Action" itself is not ideal, as the "Equipment" or "Contact" may move between "Customers.

Comment: Are these definitely both the same relationship? Obviously they're both between customers and actions but in different ways. Is it possible that you're actually describing two distinct relationships which should be given different names?

Comment: Thats an interesting suggestion - I want to build a view of all actions on the Customer view. I can still do this (just loop through all of the relations) and the only downside is I can't display all Customer related Actions in DueDate order. I'll give this a go if it seems impossible to do it with one relationship. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the schemas/migrations of all four tables?